Understanding KKT conditions through an example
I'd like to algebraically solve the following non-linear optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\mbox{maximize }&2x_1^2-7x_2^2+12x_1x_2\\
\mbox{subject to }& 2x_1+5x_2-98 \leq 0\\
&-x_1 \leq 0\\
&-x_2\leq 0
\end{align}

Constraint qualification: Slater's constraint qualification holds because $x_1=x_2=10$ is an interior point where every constraint is satisfied with strict ($<$) inequality. As such we can apply the KKT conditions to find the optimal solution.

Lagrangian:
\begin{equation}
L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\lambda})=2x_1^2-7x_2^2+12x_1x_2 - \lambda_1 (2x_1+5x_2-98) - \lambda_2(-x_1) - \lambda_3(-x_2)
\end{equation}
with $\lambda \geq 0$

Stationary conditions:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=4x_1 +12x_2 -2\lambda_1 +\lambda_2=0
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=12x_1-14x_2 -5\lambda_1 +\lambda_3=0
\end{align}

Complementary slackness conditions:
\begin{align}
\lambda_1(2x_1+5x_2-98)\\
\lambda_1(-x_1)\\
\lambda_3(-x_2)
\end{align}


Q1: To solve this problem, I evaluated $2³=8$ cases:

$\{\lambda_1>0 \vee \lambda_1=0\}\times \{\lambda_2>0 \vee \lambda_2=0\}\times \{\lambda_3>0 \vee \lambda_3=0\}$.

Is there a faster way to do this that does not require solving 8 cases as that's quite time consuming, e.g. can we somehow implicitly handle the non-negativity of the $x_1$ and $x_2$ variables?
I found the following 2 solutions satisfying primal and dual feasibility constraints and the above KKT conditions (the remaining 6 did not):

$x_1=x_2=\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ with objective value $0$
$x_1=44$, $x_2=2$, $\lambda_1=100$, $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ with objective value $4900$.

Q2: since both solutions do not have the same objective value, they cannot both be optimal. How do I determine which one is optimal? Plotting the solution, I suspect that the first solution is a saddle point and hence the 2nd solution must be optimal.
Q3: In the above example, I have 2 solutions that meet the KKT conditions, but only 1 can be optimal. If, in contrast, I had only a single solution, would this solution be by definition optimal, or could this single solution also be a saddle point in which cases the problem's true solution would be $\infty$.
Q4: I presume that, it's also possible to have an infinite number of optimal solutions (e.g. there's a face where all solutions yield the same optimal value). Will these KKT conditions find a single point on this face (e.g. a corner point) or will it yield the whole face?
